# Recurring Events and Volunteer Shifts

Tags: civievent, civivolunteer

In Civicrm I can copy an Event that takes place annually and simply update some details without starting from scratch. But the Volunteer component of that Event does not copy over with it. Is there a way to copy all the Volunteer setup too so we don't have start over from scratch to set up the Volunteer requirements and shifts again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is, but perhaps if you contact the team behind CiviVolunteer (Ginkgo Street Labs - inquire@ginkgostreet.com) they'd be able to update it for you :)

John